# Could a RPI 3B+ running Android Things support touch-display and display module with different views?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

We are currently working on a project with a Raspberry Pi 3 B that will run Android Things *NIH40K, 0.4.1-devpreview, Jun 15, 2017*. As it runs A.T. I would like to connect two separate displays, one touch screen-module ([Link](https://www.conrad.nl/nl/raspberry-pi-display-module-rb-lcd-7-raspberry-pi-a-b-b-1388955.html)) so user can interact via calculator app (making calculations) and one display-module ([Link](https://www.conrad.nl/nl/raspberry-pi-display-module-raspberry-pi-791898.html?sc.ref=Product%20Details)) that shows the outcome of the calculation.

We would like to know what technical (hardware and/or software) requirements we need to keep in mind and if it is possible (and how we can) to support the hardware within this setup?

Comment: try the raspberry-pi forum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, might fit for http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, I will try the stack exchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71797/could-a-rpi-3b-running-android-things-support-touch-display-and-display-module

Comment: Seems, you can support several displays (for example one over HDMI or DSI, other - over SPI or I2C), but you need custom driver for touch screen support.And take a look at [this](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/external-displays) overview.

Comment: Thanks Andrii, but I think it will only work for output purposes only.. How about a touch-able display, so there will be input as well? And both screens I mentioned in the link need to be connected via SPI.. How would that work out?

Comment: You can use `GPIO` pins for touchscreen input. Or `SPI/I2C` interface. Of course, if you use, for example, `I2C` for touch screen, you should use `SPI` for second screen.